# Having trouble with Try/Except logic. Getting an UnboundLocalError

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view that assigns an object to either an Event or a customEvent. It tries to do Event first, and should do customEvent if it fails. The code I have at the moment is:

```
@login_required
def addEvent(request):
    event_id = request.POST['event_id']
    user = request.POST['profile']
    user = Profile.objects.get(id = user)
    try:
        event = Event.objects.get(event_id = event_id)
        user.eventList.add(event)
    except event.DoesNotExist:
        event = customEvent.objects.get(event_id = event_id)
        user.customEventList.add(event)

return HttpResponse(status = 200)
```

However, I get told that the local variable 'event' is referenced before assignment in the "except" line. Well, isn't that the point of DoesNotExist? It couldn't be assigned? Anyone know how I'd work around this issue?

Comment: Is this exactly the way it is in your code? I mean the indentation of `user.customEventList.add(event)` ?

Comment: Yes, I just copy and pasted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is here `except event.DoesNotExist`.

It should be `except Event.DoesNotExist`

Because model name is `Event` not `event`

Comment: Oh, wow. You're so right. That was such a dumb mistake on my end. Thanks a ton.